# Image width and height with Picasso library

Tags: android, image, picasso

Is it possible to get width and height of an image, without loading it in memory using Picasso library?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking if you can get the width and height of an image without actually retrieving the image from the network?

Comment: Without loading it in memory using inJustDecodeBounds property, to be able to check if there is enough memory to load the image.